# How to get http response header in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, header, xmlhttprequest

Why this .vbs script retrieve null value?

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
Dim h: Set h = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
h.Open "HEAD", "http://google.com/", False
h.send
Dim GetLocation: Set GetLocation = h.getResponseHeader("Location")
MsgBox GetLocation
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost all HTTP libraries follow redirects by default.
Therefore you can not get `Location` header as long as you follow the redirects, so you need to stop following redirects.
I recommend two different solutions.

**#1** Achieving the final url would be the easiest way instead of getting `Location` header.

```
Option Explicit

Dim GetLocation
Const SXH_OPTION_URL = -1

Dim h
Set h = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    h.Open "HEAD", "http://google.com/", False 
    h.send
GetLocation = h.getOption(SXH_OPTION_URL) 'final URL even if redirected

MsgBox GetLocation
```

**#2** If you want to make sure you get the **first** `Location` header (not the last link in the chain of redirects), you should use [WinHttpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by disabling redirects, so you can get the header if available.

```
Option Explicit

Dim GetLocation
Const WHR_EnableRedirects = 6

Dim h
Set h = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    h.Option(WHR_EnableRedirects) = False 'disable redirects
    h.Open "HEAD", "http://google.com/", False
    h.Send
GetLocation = h.GetResponseHeader("Location") 'an error occurs if not exist

MsgBox GetLocation
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure off hand why you don't get the `Location` HTTP header, but you can debug by adjusting your code

```vb
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
Dim h: Set h = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
h.Open "HEAD", "http://google.com/", False
h.send
Dim headers: headers = h.getAllResponseHeaders()
MsgBox headers
```

Example output

```
Date: Fri, 18 Sep 2015 15:33:41 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=1
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; p="1"; ma=604800
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Thinking about it not sure if [`Location`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) is included unless the server is redirecting from a URL.

---

#### Useful Links

- [HTTP location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location)
- [getAllResponseHeaders method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536428(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the location isn't provided, it is because the winhttp service isn't registered to the server to connect to. So you can change the user-agent option with `objWinhttpReq.Option(0) = "curl"` since it works well with curl tool.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim GetLocation
Const WHR_UserAgent = 0

Dim h
Set h = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    h.Option(WHR_UserAgent ) = "curl"
    h.Open "HEAD", "http://google.com/", False
    h.Send
GetLocation = h.GetResponseHeader("Location") 'an error occurs if not exist

MsgBox GetLocation
```